# File upload in Struts2 along with the Spring CSRF token

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I use,

- Spring Framework 4.0.0 RELEASE (GA)
- Spring Security 3.2.0 RELEASE (GA)
- Struts 2.3.16

In which, I use an in-built security token to guard against CSRF attacks.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side"
        action="Category"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="POST"
        validate="true"
        id="dataForm"
        name="dataForm">

    <s:hidden name="%{#attr._csrf.parameterName}"
              value="%{#attr._csrf.token}"/>
</s:form>
```

It is a multipart request in which the CSRF token is unavailable to Spring security unless `MultipartFilter` along with `MultipartResolver` is properly configured so that the multipart request is processed by Spring.

`MultipartFilter` in `web.xml` is configured as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_login/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_side/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <description>Description</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And in `applicationContext.xml`, `MultipartResolver` is registered as follows.

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
</bean>
```

The CSRF token is now received by Spring security but doing so incurs another problem in Struts.

Uploaded file(s) is now `null` in Struts action classes like as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")
public final class CategoryAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, ModelDriven<Category>
{
    private File fileUpload;
    private String fileUploadContentType;
    private String fileUploadFileName;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Getters and setters.

    //Necessary validators as required.
    @Action(value = "AddCategory",
        results = {
            @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Category"}),
            @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Category.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
        })
    public String insert(){
        //fileUpload, fileUploadContentType and fileUploadFileName are null here after the form is submitted.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Category",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Category.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Category.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={ "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception{
        //This method is just required to return an initial view on page load.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This happens because to my guess, **the multipart request** is already processed and consumed by Spring hence, it is not available to Struts as a multipart request and therefore, the file object in a Struts action class is `null`.

Is there a way to get around this situation? Otherwise, I have now left with the only option to append the token to a URL as a query-string parameter which is highly discouraged and not recommended at all.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side"
        action="Category?%{#attr._csrf.parameterName}=%{#attr._csrf.token}"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="POST"
        validate="true"
        id="dataForm"
        name="dataForm">
    ...
<s:form>
```

<sub>**Long story short :** How to get files in a Struts action class, if Spring is made to process a mulipart request? On the other hand, if Spring is **not** made to process a multipart request then, it lakes the security token. How to overcome this situation?</sub>

Comment: Maybe try to move `struts2` filter before `Spring MultipartFilter`.

Comment: If the `struts2` filter is moved before `MultipartFilter` then, it complains about authentication throwing an exception, `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`. Moreover, `MultipartFilter` must be placed before `springSecurityFilterChain` or the token will be unavailable, in case a request is a multipart request.

Comment: In that case, try to change `struts2` filter pattern from `/*` to `*.action`.

Comment: In case, the filter pattern `*.action` is given to the `struts2` filter after moving it before `MultipartFilter`, the security strategy is skipped in its entirely. All resources are accessed publicly without any authentication at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your best bet is to create a custom [MultiPartRequest implementation](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/MultiPartRequest.html) that delegates to Spring's MultipartRequest. Here is an example implementation:

**sample/SpringMultipartParser.java**

```
package sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.Logger;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory;

public class SpringMultipartParser implements MultiPartRequest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiPartRequest.class);

    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    private MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> multipartMap;

    private MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest;

    private MultiValueMap<String, File> multiFileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, File>();

    public void parse(HttpServletRequest request, String saveDir)
            throws IOException {
        multipartRequest =
                WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, MultipartHttpServletRequest.class);

        if(multipartRequest == null) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to MultipartHttpServletRequest");
            errors.add("Unable to MultipartHttpServletRequest");
            return;
        }
        multipartMap = multipartRequest.getMultiFileMap();
        for(Entry<String, List<MultipartFile>> fileEntry : multipartMap.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = fileEntry.getKey();
            for(MultipartFile file : fileEntry.getValue()) {
                File temp = File.createTempFile("upload", ".dat");
                file.transferTo(temp);
                multiFileMap.add(fieldName, temp);
            }
        }
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getFileParameterNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(multipartMap.keySet());
    }

    public String[] getContentType(String fieldName) {
        List<MultipartFile> files = multipartMap.get(fieldName);
        if(files == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] contentTypes = new String[files.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(MultipartFile file : files) {
            contentTypes[i++] = file.getContentType();
        }
        return contentTypes;
    }

    public File[] getFile(String fieldName) {
        List<File> files = multiFileMap.get(fieldName);
        return files == null ? null : files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }

    public String[] getFileNames(String fieldName) {
        List<MultipartFile> files = multipartMap.get(fieldName);
        if(files == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] fileNames = new String[files.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(MultipartFile file : files) {
            fileNames[i++] = file.getOriginalFilename();
        }
        return fileNames;
    }

    public String[] getFilesystemName(String fieldName) {
        List<File> files = multiFileMap.get(fieldName);
        if(files == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] fileNames = new String[files.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(File file : files) {
            fileNames[i++] = file.getName();
        }
        return fileNames;
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
        return multipartRequest.getParameter(name);
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
        return multipartRequest.getParameterNames();
    }

    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        return multipartRequest.getParameterValues(name);
    }

    public List getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        for(List<File> files : multiFileMap.values()) {
            for(File file : files) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }

        // Spring takes care of the original File objects
    }
}
```

Next you need to ensure that Struts is using it. You can do this in your struts.xml file as shown below:

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser" value="spring"/>
<bean type="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest" 
      name="spring" 
      class="sample.SpringMultipartParser"
      scope="default"/>
```

**WARNING**: It is absolutely necessary to ensure that a new instance of MultipartRequest is created for every multipart request by properly setting the scope of the bean otherwise you will see race conditions.

After doing this, your Struts actions will have the file information added just as it was before. Keep in mind that validation of file (i.e. file size) is now done with filterMultipartResolver instead of Struts.

**Using Themes to auto include the CSRF token**

You might consider creating a custom theme so that you can automatically include the CSRF token in forms. For more information on how to do this see http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html

**Complete Example on Github**

You can find a complete working sample on github at https://github.com/rwinch/struts2-upload

Comment: Very valuable answer. I'm glad you found the time to write both it and the example

Comment: Given it a try. This complete example works exactly as it is. Much appreciated for taking time. One thing however, I have to ask : when no file(s) is uploaded, the content type received in the `getContentType()` method in this implementation is `application/octet-stream` (otherwise, the content type received is according to the file uploaded, `image/jpeg` for a `jpg` image, for example). Is this doing right thing?

Comment: @Tiny Your browser is most likely defaulting the Content-Type to application/octet-stream and that is where it is coming from. I know this happens for me when using Chrome. You can view the request using Chrome Dev tools to verify this. So assuming your browser is sending application/octet-stream as the default content type the answer is "Yes it is behaving properly".

Comment: Yes, the chrome developer tool shows `application/octet-stream`, when no file is uploaded. Therefore, it is fine. By the way, when no file is uploaded, the file received in the action class should be null but the file object is initialized with a file name something like `upload5500525321992133691.dat` suppresing the mandatory file validation. To avoid it (to initialized a file to `null`, when no file is chosen in the file browse), I have added one extra conditional check in the inner most `foreach` loop in the parse method like `if(!file.isEmpty()){...}`. May it have some side effect?

Comment: The slightly modified version of the `parse()` method can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/H4XNPb2u). It is experimental and I should not decide myself. The bounty will be closed tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: With any code you will want to ensure you test it well (I only quickly put this together), but I think the additional check you added is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The form encoding `multipart/formdata` is meant to be used for file upload scenarios, this is according to the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

> The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting
>   forms that contain  files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

The `MultipartResolver` class expects a file upload only, and not other form fields, this is from the javadoc:

```
/**
 * A strategy interface for multipart file upload resolution in accordance
 * with <a href="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt">RFC 1867</a>.
 *
 */
```

So this is why adding the CSRF as a form field would not work, the usual way to secure file upload requests against CSRF attacks is to send the CSRF token in a HTTP request header instead of the POST body. For that you need to make it an ajax POST.

For a normal POST there is no way to do this, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form). Either make the POST an ajax request and add the header with some Javascript, or send the CSRF token as a URL parameter as you mentioned.

If the CSRF token is frequently regenerated as it should ideally be between requests, then sending it in as request parameter is less of a problem and might be acceptable.

On the server side, you would need to configure the CSRF solution to read the token from the header, this is usually foreseen by the CSRF solution being used.

Comment: Do I need to perform everything with AJAX (CRUD operations), if I think of supplying the token in a header? If yes then, it is painful.

Comment: the rest can still use forms with the token in a hidden field. But for file upload forms, the way to pass a CSRF token is via a request header, and that can only be made using ajax

Comment: Note, if you use AJAX, you need to set Content Security Policy directives. And possibly you need to look into adding `'nonce-...'` in all of your `<script>` tags. Wouldn't recommend this approach, because it's a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance your configuration looks correct to me.  I therefore think that the problem might be some tiny bit of misconfiguration somewhere.

I faced a similar problem with Spring MVC instead of Struts, which I was able to solve with help from the Spring Security team.  For full details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397939/spring-security-3-2-csrf-support-for-multipart-requests/21448087#21448087).

You may also compare your set up with a working sample available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-csrf-multipart).  I have tested this on Tomcat 7, JBoss AS 7, Jetty and Weblogic.

If these do not work, it will be helpful if you can create a single controller, single page application with your configuration that demonstrates the problem and upload it somewhere.

Comment: If it is Spring MVC alone then, there is no problem. The configurations depicted in the question are sufficient to make it work, when there a multipart request but integration of two (or probably more) frameworks is sometimes painful and plain clumsy like in this case, Spring developers will not likely be willing to reply because there is Struts and Struts developers will also likely not be willing to reply because of Spring. Whom to ask such kind of questions, not sure, ha ha :)

Comment: I could help get your set up to work if you can upload a sample app somewhere.  I have used Spring Security with Struts and JSF so won't mind taking a look at your current set up and help get it working.

Comment: Tried for hours to upload on GitHub after signing in but unable to find a way to upload on it.

Comment: On Github you will have to create a Git repository and then commit your sample code to it.  Github provides a Git client for Windows if you are using a Windows machine.  Most Unix distributions have their own Git clients.  Alternatively, if you have a ZIP file, you may want to upload it to DropBox, Google Drive, SkyDrive or Box if you have any of those accounts and share the uploaded file with public.  Once we have debugged the problem you can remove the file.

Comment: If you don't mind then, I can think of uploading a simple project somewhere but as a beginner, I use NetBeans in which a complex ant script is generated automatically by the IDE itself. Therefore, I do not have a `pom.xml` file in my application nor I can write it myself (I have not yet built a Maven project). Can you manage without this file?

Comment: Sure, I work with ANT files and Netbeans as well so won't be a problem for me.

Comment: Uploaded an application [here](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/09ec6fe0-7809-4bae-98f4-551dedbdf054/976hj_guKh312CutO9vE9A2), [a direct link](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/download/file/44d90382-8d25-45af-bb80-0ea92d174760?rt=nOFDr7cALSzDXoxfTz13FQ2). I had to exclude all jar files from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder because of transfer limitation. You will need to change `user` and `password` in the `context.xml` file under `META-INF`. In my application, I'm using Spring 4.0.0 GA, Hibernate 4.2.7 final, Spring Security 3.2.0 GA and Tomcat 7.0.35. Can you manage to have a compatible environment?

Comment: The application contains only one JSP page with a single file element and a submit button and a corresponding action class. After successful login, it will redirect directly to this JSP page, `Test.jsp`.  Download it in due time. The link will expire in 5 days. Thanks.

Comment: I have downloaded your sample application.  Will take a look and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Thank you manish. By the way, the accepted answer now works as expected. If you have a new way then, don't forget to update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Struts user, but I think you can use the fact that the Spring `MultipartFilter` wraps the request in a `MultipartHttpServletRequest`.

First get a hold of the `HttpServletRequest`, in Struts I think you can do it something like this:

```
ServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

Then retreive the `MultipartRequest` out of it, wrapping up wrappers if necessary:

```
MultipartRequest multipart = null;
while (multipart == null)
{
    if (request instanceof MultipartRequest)
        multipart = (MultipartRequest)request;
    else if (request instanceof ServletRequestWrapper)
        request = ((ServletRequestWrapper)request).getRequest();
    else
        break;                
}
```

If this request was a multipart, get the [file](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) by the form input name:

```
if (multipart != null)
{
    MultipartFile mf = multipart.getFile("forminputname");
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This phenomenon should happen deep under the hood, when `MultipartFilter` is configured. There should not be a need to get a file in Struts action classes manually. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Tiny Well, you can tell the developers of Struts that :)