# SpringMVC with OAuth2 to Struts2 with OAuth2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, struts2, spring-security-oauth2

What are the points that should be considered when moving OAuth2 configuration from a SpringMVC application to a Struts2 application?

I've been trying to implement OAuth2 in my Struts2 application following [this SpringMVC application example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth).

I've been removing code to get the example even simpler, and now the only difference between them is the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` in the example application.

Besides both applications have the same OAuth configuration, my application keeps throwing the following exception:

> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException:
> A redirect is required to get the users approval

when example application runs.

Comment: You could start by tagging this `spring-security`; you may be lucky and get some help directly from the team, [it would not be the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21741353/1654265)...