# Invalid CSRF Token 'null' when running a curl command

Tags: java, curl, csrf

I am trying to test a backend and mimic the request being sent by the frontend using curl.

Here is the command I am using:

```
curl -c cookie.txt --cookie cookie.txt -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-CSRFToken: xxxxxxxxxx"-d @data.csv -X POST http://localhost:5050/something/save
```

I am getting the following respond:

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
```

I found a couple related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128058/invalid-csrf-token-null-was-found-on-the-request-parameter-csrf-or-header). But I am not actually using Html and JavaScript. I am trying to use curl.

Comment: You should probably not post your base64-encoded password on SO.

Comment: @TimoSta Thanks for the reminder!!

Comment: And change your password too because it is in edit history [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38108687/1).

Comment: Looks like you should be passing `X-CSRF-TOKEN` instead of `X-CSRFToken`?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Thanks a lot! I have tried using X-CSRF-TOEKN, the new error message is `Error 403 Invalid CSRF Token '6b4b9f12-8e05-41a8-8063-0772c4594a81-d' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.`